# search and report generation django admin panel

Tags: django, admin

May I get to know how to customize django admin panel with search option and report 
generation [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oq1pI.png)

Comment: defined 2 classes for search and report and registered model with class name while registering i got the error model already registered if i remove registered model then i will be able to see only 1 option so please help how to add 2 option in admin panel

Comment: @b-vinay you have to use a proxy model which just inherits the main one

Comment: Please post code and data as text, not images.